# Stable reduction and properness of moduli stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the notes:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.1048.pdf

on stable reduction, where on page 31, it's asserted that the Stable Reduction Theorem (Theorem 6.1 on page 30), is equivalent to the properness of the moduli stacks of stable curves.

My naive question is - If $R$ is a DVR with fraction field $K$, and if $X$ is a stable curve over $K$ of genus $g$, then the stable reduction theorem only guarantees a stable model of $X$ over some finite extension $R'$ of $R$. If a stable model of $X$ doesn't exist over $R$, then doesn't the natural map $\text{Spec }K\rightarrow\overline{\mathcal{M}_g}$ fail the valuative criterion?

Comment: Unlike for schemes, the valuative criterion for stacks requires one to pass to some finite extension so the existence of a unique (up to isomorphism) stable model over $R'$ is precisely the valuative criterion for $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$. The original reference is Deligne-Mumford, Theorems 4.18 and 4.19: https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Number7.pdf.

Comment: @DoriBejleri Ah! Interesting, so then I guess need to pass to a finite extension is really due to a need to remove "monodromy" coming from automorphisms of the objects?

Would I also be correct in saying that the proper regular minimal model of, say, an elliptic curve, is in general not even a semistable model? (for example, all of the Kodaira reduction types other than I_n seem to have infinite automorphism group).

Comment: @DoriBejleri Actually even the neron $N$-gons $I_n$ also seem to have infinite automorphism group, as long as $n \ge 2$, in which case any non-marked rational component will have automorphism group $G_m$. I suppose this is why the stable compactification of $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ only uses nodal cubics, and not Neron polygons? Perhaps the Deligne-Rapoport compactification $X(N)$ uses the additional data of the existence of a group law on the smooth locus as a substitute for stability?